# Pass mule message into a java component in Mule 4.3 CE

Tags: components, mule-component, callable, mule-esb, mule4

Is there a way to pass mule message/ event context into a java class in Mule 4.3 CE, as using Callable interface in Mule 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

No, and it would be a bad practice to try to do it in Mule 4 to do something like that. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/general-coding-rules#never-access-flow-variables for more details.